# Generic Type arguments as params

Tags: c#, linq, generics, expression, parameters

Does anyone know why this works

```
GetPropertyName(x => x.Ident);
```

But this does not

```
GetPropertyNames(x => x.Ident, x => x.Name);
```

Calling these two method respectively

```
public static string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<DTO, T>> pExpression)
{
    MemberExpression me = pExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (me != null) { return me.Member.Name; }

    UnaryExpression ue = pExpression.Body as UnaryExpression;
    me = ue.Operand as MemberExpression;
    if (me != null) { return me.Member.Name; }

    return null;
}

public static string[] GetPropertyNames<T>(params Expression<Func<DTO, T>>[] pExpressions)
{
    List<string> propertyNames = new List<string>();
    foreach (Expression<Func<DTO, T>> expression in pExpressions)
    {
        propertyNames.Add(GetPropertyName(expression));
    }
    return propertyNames.ToArray();
}
```

Limitations of params

Comment: whats the error you're getting? are `Indent` and `Name` the same type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only works when both properties are the same type, as both use "T".

The compiler will tell you something like Type-Arguments cannot be infered from the usage.

Modify the method to make it use object instead of T like this:

```
public static string[] GetPropertyNames(params Expression<Func<DTO, object>>[] pExpressions)
{
    List<string> propertyNames = new List<string>();
    foreach (Expression<Func<DTO, object>> expression in pExpressions)
    {
        propertyNames.Add(GetPropertyName(expression));
    }
    return propertyNames.ToArray();
}
```

And it should work.

T works as a placeholder so the compiler tries to find the Type for T that matches the complete "thing". Since you define two expressions, he tries to find a working T for both expressions, hence this requires you to have both expressions to be of the same type.

Comment: Technically both don't have to be the same type.  If one type is implicitly convertible to the other it would also work.